# Add ViewPager inside ListView Item

Tags: android

I have made a ViewPager with ImageView on each page.Now,I want to place this ViewPager inside the ListView item.

Could AnyOne Provide to way to do this

Any  answer appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I did it with scrollview. But in your case try [this](http://dallasgutauckis.com/2013/04/30/android-putting-a-viewpager-inside-a-listview/)

Comment: hi @ali,I have seen this link allready,I wanted to know way to add the ViewPager into ListView Item...thks

Comment: if you find any solution, then help me @dropandtrap